# Type Mismatch for getting year value

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

I have the error message of

> Type Mismatch

at the line of `If Year(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2) = 2015 Then`

macro shows `Year(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2)` equals to Error 2042, I'm not sure what to do with this.

The full code is here:

```
Sub WintelPatch()
'// Declare your variables.
Dim wSheet1 As Worksheet, _
wSheet2 As Worksheet, _
wSlastRow As Long, _
X As Long, _
wkbSourceBook As Workbook, _
wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook, _
worksheetName As String, _
Default As String

Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
'// Set here Workbook(Sheets) names
Set wSheet2 = wkbCrntWorkBook.ActiveSheet

'extract data from another excel file
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show
If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

    'Prompts user to choose which Worksheet they want to copy from
    MSG1 = MsgBox("Do you wish to copy from 'Overall details' ?", vbYesNo, "Name of Worksheet")
    If MSG1 = vbYes Then
        worksheetName = "Overall details"
    Else
        Default = "Sheet"
        worksheetName = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of Worksheet (Case-sensitive)", Default, Default)
    'End of first If statement
    End If

    Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
    Set wSheet1 = wkbSourceBook.Sheets(worksheetName)

    With wSheet1
    '// Here lets Find the last row of data
    wSlastRow = .Rows(.Range("B:B").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '// Now Loop through each row
    For X = 2 To wSlastRow
    'insert wSlastRow no of rows to worksheet Summary
    'wSheet1.Rows(wSlastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    If Not IsError(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2) Then
        If IsDate(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2) Then
            If Year(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2) = 2015 Then
                .Range("B" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("B" & X)
                .Range("AJ" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("J" & X)
            End If
        ElseIf IsDate("01-" & .Range("AJ" & X).Value2) Then
            If Year("01-" & .Range("AJ" & X).Value2) = 2015 Then
                .Range("B" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("B" & X)
                .Range("AJ" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("J" & X)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next X

    End With
    wkbSourceBook.Close False
End If
End With

'Free objects
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = Nothing
Set wSheet2 = Nothing
Set wkbSourceBook = Nothing
Set wSheet1 = Nothing

'// Simple Msg Box
MsgBox "Copy & Paste is Done."
End Sub
```

Here's the data in column B and AJ which are hostnames and dates my macro need to copy over another worksheet (sample data for your reference):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if the cell contains a date first:

```
For X = 2 To wSlastRow
    'insert wSlastRow no of rows to worksheet Summary
    'wSheet1.Rows(wSlastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    If Not IsError(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2) Then
        If IsDate(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2) Then
            If Year(.Range("AJ" & X).Value2) = 2015 Then
                .Range("B" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("B" & X)
                .Range("AJ" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("J" & X)
            End If
        ElseIf IsDate("01-" & .Range("AJ" & X).Value2) Then
            If Year("01-" & .Range("AJ" & X).Value2) = 2015 Then
                .Range("B" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("B" & X)
                .Range("AJ" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("J" & X)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next X
```

Comment: There's not even one data copied...all the date format is like `Jan-15`, I wonder why this is not considered date

Comment: That's not a date - a date requires a day. I'll amend the code to cater for that too. Edit: done. I also removed the `Do..Loop` as I couldn't see the point of it.

Comment: I get error message of `Type Mismatch` at line of `ElseIf IsDate("01-" & .Range("AJ" & X).Value2) Then`

Comment: @excel Perhaps you have errors in some cells? I've added a test for that too.

Comment: I have updated screenshot of my sample data for your reference:) 
Now there's no errors but just nothing is copied over to the worksheet, it means there's some errors in all data format of the cells, I'm wondering what's wrong with them

Answer (score 0):

I think that we don't need so many checking. If your cell type is `Date`, this code also should be work:

```
For X = 2 To wSlastRow
    If IsDate(.Range("AJ" & X)) Then
        If Year(.Range("AJ" & X)) = 2015 Then
            .Range("B" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("B" & X)
            .Range("AJ" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("J" & X)
        End If
    End If
Next X
```